# How to implement Simrank efficiently using Spark RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, graph, rdd

I want to implement [SimRank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SimRank) using spark rdd interface. But my dataset is too large to process that the bipartite graph has hundreds of millions of nodes, so to find the similarity score of all neighborhood pairs is computationally expensive. I try to find some existing implementations but they all seems not to be scalable. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to first take a look on the GraphX and [Graphframes](https://graphframes.github.io/graphframes/docs/_site/index.html) libraries that comes with the Apache Spark ecosystem and see if those fits your needs. They mostly bring in graph processing support on the top of RDD and Dataframes.

Comment: I think if graphx could solve my problem, then rdd is capable too?

Comment: @K_Augus  Could you solve your problem? I want to implement the same thing. But the problem is that pyspark does not support graphx, can you give me a hint?